# Magento version upgrade in SVN

Tags: svn, vendor-branch, magento

I have a Magento Enterprise Edition install in a repository, client's site is running, all is well. Now I want to upgrade this client to a new version of Magento, but the only help that EE gives me for upgrades is to delete the entire `app/code/core` directory and move the new files in.

This is, to say the least, non-optimal.

Any good thoughts on how I can do the change while preserving my SVN history cleanly?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: A svn commit would add the new modules and update the changed modules, but wouldn't identify old modules that aren't part of Magento EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good way of managing this situation, using an external library in a project under SVN, is described in the book *Version Control with Subversion*, in the section titled *Vendor Branches*. It's also available on-line:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html